# Request is not available in this context error with ajax call

Tags: packages, admin-pages

This is Sitecore 9.3 and I'm trying to build an admin page to create a package programmatically.
The aspx page location is \wwwroot\mysite\sitecore\admin\minions\package.aspx

The method is triggered on a button click. It works fine when it is a postback. But if it is an ajax call , it throws an error when setting the active site.

> Request is not available in this context

```
using (PackageWriter writer = new PackageWriter(fileNameWithPath))
            {
                using (new SecurityDisabler())
                {
                    Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("shell"); //error here
                    writer.Initialize(Installer.CreateInstallationContext());
                    PackageGenerator.GeneratePackage(packageProject, writer);
                    Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("website");
                }
            }
```

**Stack Trace:**

> at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Request()    at Sitecore.UIUtil.IsWebkit()
>   at Sitecore.UIUtil.SupportsInlineEditing()    at
>   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.SetDisableWebEditEditing(String value)
>   at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext..ctor(SiteInfo siteInfo, Boolean
>   processQueryString)    at
>   Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String name)
>   at Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite(String siteName)    at
>   SitecoreCustomTools.sitecore.admin.minions.generatepackage.GeneratePackage(GeneratePackageDataModel
>   generatePackageDataModel, String& statusMessage)    at
>   SitecoreCustomTools.sitecore.admin.minions.generatepackage.GenerateSitecorePackage(GeneratePackageDataModel
>   generatePackageDataModel)

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: @MarekMusielak,  That is the full error message. Anyways, I have updated the stack trace. Could you please check.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why request would not be available in the ajax call. Do you run any background job or try to execute some of the code async?

Comment: @MarekMusielak. No. If it is postback, the site is "shell" already & it works. But in ajax call, the site is "admin". And now, setting it to "shell" throws the error.